# Laravel Polymorphic Relation for Product and Image

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and trying to figure out how to use polymorphic relationship between **Product** and its **images**.

I have designed both the models for Product and Image and defined the relationship accordingly but in my case I have used **object_id** and **object_type** rather then **imageable_id** and **imageable_type**.

Here is my structure of product and image model

```
class Product extends Model {

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id', 'added_by', 'title',
        'product_unique_code', 'description', 'currency', 'product_status'
    ];

    /**
     * Get category this product belongs to
     * @return Category
     */
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get user who added this product
     * @return User
     */
    public function addedByUser() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * List of images
     * @return type
     */
    public function images() {
        return $this->morphMany(App\Image::class, 'object');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Image extends Model {

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'image_path', 'image_status', 'object_id', 'object_type', 
        'image_width', 'image_height'
    ];

    /**
     * Product own this image
     * @return Product
     */
    public function object() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Here is the requirement, Images would be uploaded while creating a new product like images would be uploaded before you save product similar to entering details for product before storing into database, so how to perform this task using the above model structure?

One more thing I want to use custom polymorphic types instead of the complete class name like App\Product in object_type field, as suggested here I have registered **morphMap** in **boot** function of my **AppServiceProvider**, but it is still taking **App\Product** instead of **'products'**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
    'products' => App\Product::class,
]);
```